# Can you export excel spreadsheets based on a selection in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I have a radio group that filters my table to show whether items are active, inactive or both. There is also a button that I am using to export an excel document of the table. My current button downloads all the records. What I want is to export the document based on the filter so if active is selected and showing and the download button is pressed, only active records will be exported

My code:
Controller:

```
public function filter()
{
    $energy = Energy::where('isredundant', 0)->paginate(10);
    return view('admin.staff', ['staff1' => $staff1]);
}

public function filtered()
{
    $energy = Energy::where('isredundant', 1)->paginate(10);
    return view('admin.staff', ['staff1' => $staff1]);
}

public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'allrecords.xlsx');
}

public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'AllReport.xlsx');
}

public function exportactive()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExportactive, 'ActiveRecords.xlsx');
}

public function exportredundant()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExportredundant, 'RedundantRecords.xlsx');
}
```

my button:

```
<div>    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/export_excel/excel">Generate Report</a></div>
```

I tried to use 3 different buttons but that just looks messy. I'm sure there's an easier method

Comment: For starters, two of your methods have the same name: `export`. That needs addressing.

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question rings a bell, from yesterday, from another account :)

Comment: could you link such question? would have have been of more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way

**in controller**

```
public function exportactive(Request $request)
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExportactive($request->ids), 'ActiveRecords.xlsx');
}
```

**in UsersExportactive() class**

```
private $ids;

public function __construct($ids)
{
    $this->ids = $ids;
}
```

**and do a query for that for like that in UsersExportactive() class**

```
Model::whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
```

**and in view use your export button as a submit button like below**

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="1"/>active
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="2"/>inactive
<input type="submit" id="download" value="download Excel"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="radio" name="download" id="x86"/>active<br />
<input type="radio" name="download" id="x64"/>inactive<br />
<input type="button" id="download" value="download"/>
```

```js
var radio_x86 = document.getElementById('x86');
var radio_x64 = document.getElementById('x64');

var button = document.getElementById('download');

button.onclick = downloadFile;

function downloadFile() {
    if (radio_x86.checked) {
        window.open("/app/test");
    } else if (radio_x64.checked) {
        window.open("/app/test1");
    } else {
        alert("Please check one of the options first.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to address your naming scheme... You have two radios with one name, and a button with the ID of that name. It's not going to cause programming issues, but it's just confusing. Not to mention you use Windows OS 32 bit and 64 bit naming of the radios (x86 and x64), but it seems that these radios relate to active and inactive. I'd guess you copied this code sample from somewhere and didn't update the names.

Comment: There is a very tenuious link between Question and Answer here!

Comment: @JustCarty The naming scheme has changed, this was for test purposes, hence why the names were not really a concern